# The model passed into the dictionary is of type 1 but this dictionary requires a model of type 2

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-express

This is my whole error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[application.Models.model]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'application.Models.TABLE1'.

My view:

```
@model application.Models.TABLE1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
 }

<h2>Update</h2>
```

My controller logic for the view:

```
//GET: /TABLE1/Update/

    public ActionResult Update(string id)
    {
        IEnumerable<TABLE2> table2 = db.TABLE2;
        IEnumerable<TABLE1> table1 = db.TABLE1;
        string context = "Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=*******;User ID=******;Password=*****";

        foreach (var row in table1)
        {

            string strAddr = row.ADDRESS1 + "+" + row.CITY + "+" + row.ST + "+" + row.ZIP + "+" + row.COUNTRY;

            GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse myCoordenates = new GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse();
            myCoordenates = GoogleMapsDll.GoogleMaps.GetGeoCodedResults(strAddr);
            if (myCoordenates.Results != null && myCoordenates.Results.Length > 3)
            {
                string strLat = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lat.ToString();
                string strLong = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lng.ToString();

                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE TABLE1 SET Lat = '" + strLat + "' , Lng = '" + strLong + "'" + "WHERE ID = '" + row.ID + "' ";

                    SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(strQueryUpdate, myConnection);
                    myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }

        }

        return View(table2);

    }
```

I have searched stack overflow, and found many answers regarding similar errors, but i cannot seem to find one that fits mine. I am not sure where or why a different model item is passed into the dictionary. Any suggestions or answers as to were my problem may be occurring or how it may be fixed would be helpful. If any more information would be helpful just ask and I will include it.

Comment: It's because `table2` hasn't been evaluated yet, It's still an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Your problem is exactly the same as the usual problem when this error is seen. I don't understand how you "cannot seem to find one that fits" yours. The View argument (variable `table2`) very obviously does not hold an instance of type `TABLE1`, just like the error message says.

Comment: It is because I did not fully understand the problem. I do now, as well as I was not getting this problem yesterday and had changed nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your model type in the view to match what you are passing as the model.

In your Controller, you have

```
IEnumerable<TABLE2> table2 = db.TABLE2;
// ...
return View(table2);
```

but in your view you have

```
@model application.Models.TABLE1
```

You either need to pass a single TABLE1 as your model into `View(..)` or change your view's model to be

```
@model IEnumerable<application.Models.TABLE2>
```

(The Dictionary the error is referring to is the ViewData dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Your view is expecting an instance of `TABLE1` as the model but you are passing it an `IEnumerable<TABLE2>`. So not only do you have a mismatch of types, you are giving it the wrong entity type.

Either change your view to accept an `IEnumerable`, for example:

```
@model IEnumerable<application.Models.TABLE1>
```

Or only pass it a single instance, for example:

```
return View(table1.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Your view expects an object of type

```
@model application.Models.TABLE1
```

In your action method, you pass `table2` to your view, which has the compile time type of `IEnumerable<TABLE2>` and the runtime type `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<application.Models.model>`

These types are different, so the View doesn't know what to do with it.